# Bootlooping LG Volt will not connect w/ ADB

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot-loop, lg

Rooted LG Volt is bootlooping after build.prop and cpu setting changes, and I am unable to connect via ADB to restore build.prop or reflash system

How can I get the phone to connect via ADB?

Attempted to do factory reset from stock recovery, which was successful but there was no change in bootloop When phone is connected to PC during bootloop, it connects as Charge Only, and ADB doesnt recognize the device. When phone is in recovery and "Apply update from ADB" is selected, the phone connects to the computer, but Windows throws error "configuration descriptor request failed", and device is not recognized by ADB. Uninstalled all phone drivers from computer using USBDeview and Device Manager.

Have Android Studio, Android SDK, and ADB installed on Windows 8.1 computer. There are no issues with the ports or cable, tested several different ones.

I do not have CWM recovery, was previously using rooted stock OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by booting into Download Mode (with the phone off, hold Vol+ while plugging in USB to computer).

There were some files that needed to be downloaded, including the LG Flash Tool, which was used to flash the stock ROM to the phone.

After flashing, the phone was in its original pre-activated state but at least it functioned!

- [Unbrick method for LG Volt (Boost/Virgin)](http://www.vmroms.com/index.php?topic=874.0)
- [GSM-Forum: LG Flash Tool](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f177/lg-flash-tool-free-no-need-b2b-user-pass-1628819/)
- [Android Forums: Fix `Factory Reset Status 2` errors](http://androidforums.com/threads/fix-factory-reset-status-2.858366/) - for an after-flash fix to boot

Comment: http://www.vmroms.com/index.php?topic=874.0   for unbrick method

Comment: http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f177/lg-flash-tool-free-no-need-b2b-user-pass-1628819/   for LG flash tool

Comment: http://androidforums.com/threads/fix-factory-reset-status-2.858366/   for an after-flash fix to boot

Comment: good to hear you managed to solve your problem! You can accept your own answer so other people can see that this is the working solution! :)