# LG Volt is stuck on Boot-Loop

Tags: boot-loop

As I was using one of the apps on my phone. It suddenly turned off then kept turning off and on going through the same process. I tried taking the battery out for a while, but that never worked either it just kept proceeding to turn off and on. What should I do?

Comment: Related: **[Bootlooping LG Volt will not connect w/ ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126932/bootlooping-lg-volt-will-not-connect-w-adb)**

Answer (score 0):

This might not help your device:

1. Go To Recovery Mode `Hold Power Button + Volume Down`
2. Navigate using Volume Buttons
3. Choose Wipe User Data/ Factory Reset
4. Reboot your phone